# What does "pullback" mean in general?

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, pullback

I've seen the word "pullback" used in a lot of situations. Examples are as follows.

> **(In category theory)** Given morphisms $f:X\to M,\ g:Y\to M$. A pullback square consists of $f,g$ and two other morphisms $\eta:L\to X$ and $\xi:L\to Y$ such that
>
> - $f\eta=g\xi$
> - Any other pair of morphisms $\eta':L'\to X$ and $\xi':L'\to Y$ for which $f\eta'=g\xi'$ can be factored through $\eta$ and $\xi$.

Another usage is in differential geometry.

> **(In differential geometry)** If $F:M\to N$ is a smooth map and $\omega$ is a differential form on $N$, the pullback $F^*\omega$ is a differential form on $M$, defined as...(omitted)

I am curious whether there is a link between these two concepts, as they are both called pullback. Tntuition tells me the pullback in category theory is supposed to be a boarder concept, and we should be able to describe the pullback of a differential form using the language of category theory. However I fail to see the connection.

Other examples are welcome.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on pullback has an example where the categorical notion (also called fibre product) is related to the pullback bundle from differential geometry.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809276/trying-to-understand-the-use-of-the-word-pullback-pushforward), and also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873460/is-there-a-relationship-between-the-pullback-in-differential-geometry-and-that-i).

Comment: This is not an easy question to give a short answer to: "pullback" has several different meanings which are related but sometimes indirectly. The categorical definition generalizes pulling back bundles, such as vector bundles, and this meaning in turn gets generalized to pulling back any kind of "data" on a space $Y$ along a map $f : X \to Y$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809276/trying-to-understand-the-use-of-the-word-pullback-pushforward/809343#809343 for some discussion.